# Сортировка многомерного массива по значению ключа с сохранением порядка

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть многомерный массив, нужно отсортировать его по значению `count`:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'Апельсины', 'count' => '0', ), 
    1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'title' => 'Ананасы', 'count' => '0' ), 
    2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'title' => 'Абрикосы', 'count' => '0' ), 
    3 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'title' => 'Авокадо', 'count' => '0' ), 
    4 => array ( 'id' => '5', 'title' => 'Айва', 'count' => '1' ), 
    5 => array ( 'id' => '6', 'title' => 'Аннона', 'count' => '0' ), 
    6 => array ( 'id' => '7', 'title' => 'Алыча', 'count' => '0' ), 
    7 => array ( 'id' => '8', 'title' => 'Араза', 'count' => '0' ), 
    8 => array ( 'id' => '9', 'title' => 'Гранат', 'count' => '0' ), 
    9 => array ( 'id' => '10', 'title' => 'Груша', 'count' => '0'), 
    10 => array ( 'id' => '11', 'title' => 'Яблоки', 'count' => '0'));
```

Мне нужно, чтобы count был от наибольшего к наименьшему, а все остальные значения(в данном случете, у которых `count = 0`) остались именно в том порядке, какие есть в массиве.

Подглядел в интернете функцию:

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){ 
        if($a['count'] == $b['count']){
                return 0;
            }
        return ($a['count'] > $b['count']) ? -1 :1;
    });
```

Наибольшие значения правда попадают вверх массива, НО все остальные у которых `count = 0` беспорядочно перемешиваются.
Результатом такой сортировки будет массив:

```
arr_new = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '5', 'title' => 'Айва', 'count' => '1' ), 
    1 => array ( 'id' => '8', 'title' => 'Араза', 'count' => '0' ), 
    2 => array ( 'id' => '9', 'title' => 'Гранат', 'count' => '0' ), 
    3 => array ( 'id' => '10', 'title' => 'Груша', 'count' => '0' ), 
    4 => array ( 'id' => '11', 'title' => 'Яблоки', 'count' => '0' ), 
    5 => array ( 'id' => '7', 'title' => 'Алыча', 'count' => '0' ), 
    6 => array ( 'id' => '6', 'title' => 'Аннона', 'count' => '0' ), 
    7 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'title' => 'Ананасы', 'count' => '0' ),
    8 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'title' => 'Абрикосы', 'count' => '0' ), 
    9 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'title' => 'Авокадо', 'count' => '0' ), 
    10 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'Апельсины', 'count' => '0'));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы те ключи у которых значения равны друг другу не пересортировывались. Другими словами, как получить массив вида:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '5', 'title' => 'Айва', 'count' => '1', ),
    1 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'Апельсины', 'count' => '0' ), 
    2 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'title' => 'Ананасы', 'count' => '0' ), 
    3 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'title' => 'Абрикосы', 'count' => '0' ), 
    4 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'title' => 'Авокадо', 'count' => '0' ), 
    5 => array ( 'id' => '6', 'title' => 'Аннона', 'count' => '0' ), 
    6 => array ( 'id' => '7', 'title' => 'Алыча', 'count' => '0' ), 
    7 => array ( 'id' => '8', 'title' => 'Араза', 'count' => '0' ), 
    8 => array ( 'id' => '9', 'title' => 'Гранат', 'count' => '0' ), 
    9 => array ( 'id' => '10', 'title' => 'Груша', 'count' => '0' ), 
    10 => array ( 'id' => '11', 'title' => 'Яблоки', 'count' => '0'));
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Значение id нельзя использовать в качестве второго поля сортировки? Т.е. в вашем примере начальный порядок по возрастанию id - это случайность, или это именно то, что нужно?

Comment: @reshu порядок id  это случайность!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете функцию сортировки `usort` то получаете только значения элементов без доступа к ключам. Однако, если вы воспользуетесь функцией `uksort`, то на вход получите ключи, и в таком случае также сможете обратиться и к значениям элементов.

```
uksort($arr, function($akey, $bkey) use ($arr){
                 $cmp = $arr[$bkey]['count'] - $arr[$akey]['count'];
                 return $cmp == 0 ? $akey - $bkey : $cmp;
             });
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Переопределив ключи с помощью array_values(),  получается итоговый массив, который требовалось получить!